# How to disallow docker cp command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created a docker image for a product. Same docker image will be deployed on customer's place for evaluation (POC)

The docker contains machine learning models which we don't want them to access using:

1. docker cp
2. docker exec

Wanted to know is there any way we can disable access to the docker container/image

Any help is highly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: You can encrypt the model and store the encryption keys in a tool such as HashiCorp's Vault. Valut has audit logs to know who accesses your keys. If the customer has root access on the node, I don't think there is a way to prevent them to access your containers.

Comment: Relatedly, if the customer can run any `docker` command, they can trivially get root access on the node.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had faced similar issue as I did not want the user to enter into my postgresql database container and did some research.
You cannot disable docker exec command or the docker cp command.
The user can always enter into your container.

Only solution is you have to make sure no sensitive information is available for the user inside the container.

I have changed my approach in the database scheduling logic and now no sensitive information is shared. So I dont have any problem with user entering into my container.